# React-Redux design approach - Redux action or local function for two-way binding of editable text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Good day,

I have read through a number of SO posts which were helpful in progressing my problem, but I still have not found anything concrete information on whether there is an established method for the following scenario I face:

I have an application that allows a user to either:

1. Add a graph; or
2. Edit an existing graph

When either the 'add graph' button or the 'edit graph' button is clicked, a side-drawer opens. The fields for for the x-axis label, y-axis label and chart title are either blank (for case (1)) or have fields already populated (for case (2)). The fields themselves are editable text input fields.

Currently, when a graph is added, I create a UUID for the graph and then the user can enter text into the fields, and the click save. When save is clicked a Redux action is dispatched to save the content of the fields in the Redux store. The two-way is binding between the text field values and the local state which contains those values initially. Once the 'save' button is clicked and the Redux action fires, the local state is set to empty strings for each field. So Redux is only used when we actually hit the save button.

Now, when an existing graph is selected, I populate the text fields of the side-drawer with the Redux state via mapStateToProps. I use two way binding that is between the text input fields and the Redux store via Redux actions incorporating debouncing to try reduce the number of actions fired off. This means that essentially a slow typer would cause a Redux action to be fired for every key stroke when editing the fields.

I do not like that we have different methods of two-way binding depending on whether the user clicks 'edit' or 'add'. I also do not like having so many Redux actions fired off for something as simple as adding or removing a letter from a word.

I then went through SO and the Redux documents and found that in general people advised that one should not initialise local state with Redux state via props. What I wanted to do was actually copy the Redux state describing the existing content of the fields (when edit is clicked) into the local state and then have the two-way binding in the local state, similar to what I have for the Case (1) scenario. This then eliminates numerous Redux actions being fired off in quick succession and I can use the same two-way binding irrespective of whether 'add' or 'edit' is clicked. But after reading through the documents it seems this is a bad idea for in the case that there is a an unexpected re-render and the local state is reset mid-way through editing, as well as having two sources of truth.

Having the two-way binding in the local state for an added graph and in Redux for an edited graph is quite confusing and does not provide clean and consistent code for those who will need to maintain this code base. Is there a established method that provides for such a scenario? I imagine editing posts on social media would be a similar context to the problem I am facing.

I have not provided my code as it is not a coding question in itself but rather a design problem and my Redux code is split over several files. But I am happy to provide the code if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, good question. This is a question that comes up quite a bit, especially with how Redux works. Redux has always, in my opinion, forced the question of, "where should this state live?". Now, I know that the docs do give a pretty clear delineation on what state should live in Redux, but when you begin creating an application, it can still be challenging.

For your particular problem, I would choose one or the other - either use local state for both add and edit or use Redux for both add and edit. To have one in Redux and one in local state is, like you said, confusing. Personally, if there is not a lot of data and not a lot of business logic/computational code, I would use local state. It is okay to use state from Redux to set your initial state, i.e., `mapStateToProps` -> `useState()` (if you are using hooks). Once you populate your local state from Redux, the only other time that data reaches Redux is when your component is finished working with that data. I would not be worried about "unexpected re-render and the local state is reset mid-way through editing". If that happens, you have a bug that needs to be fixed and that is not the fault of Redux and passing state to the component.

I hope this helps. Please feel free to ask more questions if you would like or need clarification.

Comment: thanks for the great response. That is very good to know that unexpected re-renders shouldnt be a concern due to Redux. The reason Redux is used for this part of app is because there are a few different pages a user can browse through using React-router. Redux was used to avoid losing any state whilst routing about (I inherited this). Would it be ok to perhaps load the Redux state into local state in the 'edit' button call back and then only save the local state to Redux when the 'save' button is clicked? This way a user can also cancel their edit without the state being overwritten

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how you can handle the state. Load it initially from Redux, allow the user to interact with the form via local state.

Comment: If that answers your questions, feel free to mark this question as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks